# Server IP address cannot be found using XAMPP

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to load my website using XAMPP but receive the following error message.

[image: Error Message]

This website was built using code ignitor and has been placed inside the htdcos folder of xampp.

Below is a screenshot of the XAMPP control panel.

[image: XAMPP Control Panel]

Furthermore, below is a screenshot of my htdcos folder.

[image: htdocs folder]

The file name is media.einnovation.com.

Below is a screenshot of the media.einnovation sub folder.

[image]

From here I tried to load the website from the index of my local host. I have also tried https://localhost/media.einnovation.com and it still does not work.

Below is the database.php file confiugration for the website.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'einnoven_media1',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Would anyone happen to know what the issue is?

Comment: you will find it `http://localhost/yourfoldername/index.php` only put your folder name in it, that follows htdocs

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the XAMPP control panel?

Comment: You have to start your Apache and Mysql in XAMPP, Once started you can run in browser like `http://localhost/yourfoldername/controllername/functionname`;

Comment: @nbk I tried the above suggestion and got a error 404 on the page load. I used http://localhost/media.einnovation.com/index.php

Comment: @Gokul I tried that suggestion too and got an error 404 message.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I have updated the question to have a screenshot of the XAMPP control panel.

Comment: that informatin i not helpful,a 404 means on that position is no folder or no file as we don't see how htdocs look lie we can't help you

Comment: @nbk I am adding a screenshot of my htdocs folder in the question.

Comment: and also the subfolder as the must be the index.php or html or what ever

Comment: @nbk I have added a screenshot of the sub folder in the question.

Comment: ok, that looks good but htaccess can prohibit access

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223713/discussion-between-omegablastoise-and-nbk).